# Kubernetes new pod created, old deleted

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, typeorm

I have a nodejs (nestjs) application running in a pod which downloads large csv files and then uploads these to a database (mysql, typeorm)

I was tailing the logs to see the progress of the csv download and database insert
Suddenly a new pod is created and the nestjs application is then started (I can see that in the logs of the new pod). I can not find any errors anywhere, the new pod does not have any and the old pod does not exist anymore.

Everything seem to work fine with smaller amount of csv files but the one I am experiencing this in has over 1000 csv files and many of those are 300-400mb

Does anyone know what can cause this kind of behavior (or how I find any errors that might have caused this) ?

Comment: The application may crash because your host’s storage fills up during upload (or in the Deployment yaml file, you set limit for storage consumption), in this case, k8s considers the pod  “unhealthy” and creates a new pod to solve the problem.

Comment: Running out of either memory or local disk ("ephemeral storage") could cause this; you'd likely see the old pod as "Evicted" in `kubectl get pods`.

Comment: Now the pod restarted and I was able to get the last state from the describe. It says last state Terminated, Reason Error and Exit Code 139. I googled this and it does not seem very trivial to debug.
I have mounted a 100gb disk where the csv files are downloaded and there should be plenty of space.
The ephemeral storage is set to 4gb.